# How to trigger animations whe the site is visible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I've been using W3.CSS Animations animations for my sites for simple "fadein" effects but I realize that they trigger when the page is loaded, if you have the site in the background the animations trigger anyway so they are easy to miss, is there a way to trigger animations only when the window is visible for example like this site:https://www.aristidebenoist.com/?

I use a little hack with Jquery however you need to hover for it to work so i'm not really convinced about it, any other way to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).hover(function(){
    $("body").css("display", "block").fadeIn(2000);
    });
    });
```

alternatively is there a way to trigger animations when a div is showing on screen (that doesn't involve scrolling)?

Comment: maybe this will help? https://memorynotfound.com/call-javascript-function-page-load/

Comment: Try using $(window).on('load', function(){});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need [Document.hasFocus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus). click the iframe below to set focus

```js
function checkPageFocus()
{
  if (document.hasFocus())
  {
    $("#showMe").fadeIn(1200);
    console.log("The document has the focus.");
  }
  else
  {
    console.clear()
    console.log("The document doesn't have the focus, click me!");
    setTimeout(checkPageFocus, 500);
  }
}
setTimeout(checkPageFocus, 500);
```

```css
#showMe{display:none;width:300px;height:200px;background:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showMe">The document has the focus.</div>
```

Comment: This did the trick. Is it correct  prefomance-wise if I add the ShowMe Id to the whole body or could I have problems with more complex code?

Comment: I can't tell but you should try it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

- jQuery.ready / DOMContentLoaded occurs when all of the HTML is ready to interact with, but often before its been rendered to the screen.
- The load event occurs when all of the HTML is loaded, and any subresources like images are loaded.
- Use setTimeout to allow the page to be rendered before your code runs.

> You should run your animations when the document has completely loaded
>   & rendered , not the best way but you can put a setTimeout function of
>   atleast 300ms at the end of the document

When everything has loaded (not rendered)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){ 
    // Everything has loaded! 
});
```

If you are using images

```
document.querySelector('img.my-image').addEventListener('load', function(){
   // The image is ready!
});
```

Run When My Current Changes Have Actually Rendered

```
setTimeout(function(){
   // Everything will have rendered here
});
```

Source : [eager.io/blog](https://eager.io/blog/how-to-decide-when-your-code-should-run/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("body").css("display","block").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").css("display","block").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  //your code
});
```